# nginx setup fo location

Tags: magento, nginx

I have such configuration more my magento store in nginx:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name domain.com;
root /www-data/domain.com/www;
access_log /www-data/domain.com/logs/nginx.access.log main;
error_log  /www-data/domain.com/logs/nginx.error_log info;
index index.php;

location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
}

location /app/                { deny all; }
location /includes/           { deny all; }
location /lib/                { deny all; }
location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
location /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
location /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
location /var/                { deny all; }

location ~* "^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|pdf|zip|tar|t?gz|mp3|wav|swf)$" {
    expires    max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    access_log off;
}

location  /. {
    return 404;
}

location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php;
}

location ~ .php/ {
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

location ~ .php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }

    fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
    expires        off;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

And I need to create new location section for admin area, which runs over standart index.php, but with long timeout.

So I need for paths like /admin/* or /index.php/admin/* to have timeout 600

Can anyone help me and get sample for such location?

As I understand it must be something li this:

```
# Magento Admin
location ^~ /index.php/backoffice/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    expires        off;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

But this config getting me **Access denied**, so I think **fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME** must be with other value.

Answer (score 0):

## Nginx Time Out

The following is the full list of time out commands *I know*. I think [fastcgi_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout) is what you need.

```
# Magento Admin
location ^~ /admin/ {
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    client_header_timeout 600;
    client_body_timeout 600;
    send_timeout 600;
}
```

You can also try     `location ^ /admin/ {`

**Variation**: Considering the nginx wiki, the [send_timeout directive](http://wiki.codemongers.com/NginxHttpCoreModule#send_timeout) is responsible for setting general timeout of response. For FastCGI there's `fastcgi_read_timeout` which is affecting the [fastcgi process response timeout](http://wiki.codemongers.com/NginxHttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_read_timeout).

Comment: I know that I must use fastcgi_read_timeout and I using it - I don't know how to create location for admin area. location ^~ /index.php/admin/ { fastcgi_read_timeout 600; fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock; fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; } gets me Access denied page, and location ^~ /admin/ {...} not working, because all admin urls goes with index.php/admin in url

Comment: such conf will get notice from nginx at all and I also updated question - I trying to say that would not work (in my added config) line with fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
and I don't know which correct config line must be here